# php - create,dynamically, an array initialized with N null elements

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I want to create dynamically an array with N (without knowking N) elements.

Something like a function

```
public function create_array($num_elements){

     .....
}
```

that return me something like

```
//call the function.... 
create_array(3);

//and the output is: 
array{
   0 => null
   1 => null
   2 => null
}
```

I've already thought about **`array_fill`** and a simple **`foreach`** loop.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: do yourself and everyone else a favour and just use array_fill

Comment: is **`array_fill`** the best solution for you?

Comment: `array_fill` is a core function - nothing will be faster than that. What would you expect from the "best solution"?

Comment: The solution which works best. If **`array_fill`** is the function which works faster and easiest, probably it's the _best solution_ (personal opinion).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually a call to [`array_fill`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) should be sufficient:

```
//...
public function create_array($num_elements){
    return array_fill(0, $num_elements, null);
}
//..

var_dump(create_array(3));
/*
array(3) {
  [0]=> NULL
  [1]=> NULL
  [2]=> NULL
}
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_elements; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = null;
}
```

Comment: this is the most obvious solution, and the best (for my test) since the other solutions are not faster than this!

Answer (score 1):

```
array_fill(0, $element, null);
```

using this php function, you can create array with starting index 0, and all will have null value.

Answer (score 0):

Do `array_fill` and `foreach` not work?

Of course, the simplest solution that comes to mind is

```
function create_array($num_elements) {
    $r = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_elements; $i++)
        $r[] = null;
    return $r;
}
```

`array_fill` should also work:

```
function create_array($num_elements) {
    return array_fill(0, $num_elements, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of `array_fill` sounds like the easiest solution:

```
$arr = array_fill($start_at, $num_elements, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **foreach** loop you can simply use [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, `range` doesn't give us a way to set a default value like `array_fill` does. Close, though!